# Relacionamento 1 - N Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de teste e estou com um problema com relacionamento 1-N com o Entity.

## Model Cab_Venda:

```
  public Cab_Venda() {
   Det_Venda = new HashSet < Det_Venda > ();
  }

  public int id {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public int idCliente {
   get;
   set;
  }

  [Column(TypeName = "date")]
  public DateTime data {
   get;
   set;
  }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(6)]
  public string hora {
   get;
   set;
  }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(1)]
  public string situacao {
   get;
   set;
  }

  [Column(TypeName = "date")]
  public DateTime dataExpedicao {
   get;
   set;
  }

  [Column(TypeName = "date")]
  public DateTime dataAceite {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public virtual Usuario Usuario {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public virtual ICollection < Det_Venda > Det_Venda {
   get;
   set;
  }
```

## Model Det_Venda

```
    public int id {
  get;
  set;
 }

 public int idCab {
  get;
  set;
 }

 public int idProduto {
  get;
  set;
 }

 public int idPreco {
  get;
  set;
 }

 public virtual Cab_Venda Cab_Venda {
  get;
  set;
 }

 public virtual Preco Preco {
  get;
  set;
 }

 public virtual Produtos Produtos {
  get;
  set;
 }
```

Estou recebendo uma coleção de Produtos e preciso inserir um `Cab_Venda` e com os produtos desta venda no `Det_Venda`. Na minha `Controller` estou com o seguinte código:

```
    List < Det_Venda > listDetVenda = new List < Det_Venda > ();

using(var db = new LojaAppContext()) {

 var idUsuario = Int32.Parse(Session["idUsuario"].ToString());


 var carrinho = db.Carrinho.Where(p => p.idUsuario == idUsuario).ToList();

 Cab_Venda order = new Cab_Venda() {
  data = DateTime.Now,
   hora = "142626",
   situacao = "Aguardando liberação",
   dataExpedicao = DateTime.Now,
   dataAceite = DateTime.Now
 };

 db.Cab_Venda.Add(order);
 db.SaveChanges();


 List < Det_Venda > listProdutos = new List < Det_Venda > ();

 foreach(var item in carrinho) {

  Preco preco = db.Preco.FirstOrDefault(p => p.idProduto == item.idProduto);

  Det_Venda dt = new Det_Venda() {
   idCab = order.id,
    idProduto = item.idProduto,
    idPreco = preco.id
  };

  listProdutos.Add(dt);
 }

 listProdutos.ForEach(dt => db.Det_Venda.Add(dt));
 db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Mas ao salvar da o seguinte erro:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

```
Linha 41:                 db.Cab_Venda.Add(order);
Linha 42:                 db.SaveChanges();
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que poderia ser?

Comment: Procure qual o erro dentro da propriedade EntityValidationErrors e compartilhe conosco. Aparentemente você esta salvando antes Cab_Venda sem fazer o vinculo com Dat_Venda em um relacionamento obrigatório!

Answer (score 0):

Mapeamento do EF, você consegue trabalhar meio que de forma dinâmica, você quer 1-N do tipo 1 Cliente tem N pedidos?

Se sim;

```
public class Cliente 
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Nome { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Pedido> Pedidos {get; set;}
}

public class Pedido
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int PedidoId {get; set;}
    public DateTime Data {get; set;}

    public virtual Cliente Cliente {get; set;}
}
```

O EF trabalha com convenções, então, se você falar ENTITY+ID (ClienteId, PedidoId), mas isso é pra outra pergunta. Se você quiser mapear na mão, é simples também, na classe de mapeamento do pedido inclua;

```
public class PedidoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Pedido>
{
    public PedidoMap()
    {
        ToTable("Pedidos");

        HasRequired(x => x.Cliente)
            .WithMany(x => x.Pedidos)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PedidoId);
    }
}
```